# После запуска State.set() в aiogram вылетает ошибка

Tags: python, aiogram, pymongo

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import logging
from Class_States import CreateandAdd_states
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.mongo import MongoStorage
import pymongo

# Объект бота
bot = Bot(token="456456456456456456456")
# Хранилище состояний
storage = MongoStorage(host= "telegramb0t-shard-2.qqthh.mongodb.net", port = 27017,username="5464",password=5464)
# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

@dp.message_handler(commands="test",state = "*")
async def enter_test(message:types.Message):
    await message.answer("Вы начили тест.\n Вопрос 1:Бла-Бла-бла")
    await CreateandAdd_states.Q1.set() # дальше этого места программа не уходит

@dp.message_handler(state = CreateandAdd_states.Q1)
async def answer_Q1(messsage:types.Message, state:FSMContext): 

    await message.answer("Второй впопрос ")
    answer = messsage.text 

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["answer1"] = answer
        print("Data =" ,data)

    await dp.storage.close()
    await dp.storage.wait_closed()
    await state.finish() #обнуление данных состояния

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Запуск бота
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Ошибка:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ошибки стоит смотреть от 3 к 1 картинке

Comment: Исправьте вопрос, нажав [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1375585/edit) под вопросом и вставьте трасер ошибки в текстовом формате. Удобней читать, копировать, искать